# How would I call the method to the Driver class and be able to print the answer. Read Body for Details

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, methods, matrix-multiplication

This is a program to multiply two matrices(with set values) with each other. How would I call the method 'mult' to use in my Driver Class? Would this code even function the way that I want it to? I was thinking that you could make an object and use THAT to call the method but I don't know how. **I'm not allowed to use a constructor!(For APCSA)**

```java
package tester;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a[][] = { { 1, 2, -2, 0 },
                    { -3, 4, 7, -2 },
                    { 6, 0, 3, 1 } };
        int b[][] = { { -1, 3 },
                    { 0, 9 },
                    { 1, -1 },
                    {4, -5} };
        System.out.println();//How would I call the method 'mult'?
    }
}
```

```java
package tester;
public class Tester2 {  
  int[][] mult(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    int[][] c = new int[a.length][b[0].length];
    int cell = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < c.length; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < c[row].length; col++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
          cell += a[row][i] * b[i][col];
        }
        c[row][col] = cell;
      }
    }
    return c;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mult` method is an instance method of the `Tester2` class.  The way to call it is to instantiate a `Tester2` object and then call `mult` on the result.  The most direct answer to your question is therefore:

```
(new Tester2()).mult(a, b)
```

But you talk about not wanting to use a constructor.  I'm not sure what that means exactly.  If you mean you can't CALL a constructor, then there's no way to use the code you show since the only way to call `mult` is to first create an instance of `Tester2`.  This will cause `Tester2`'s default constructor to be called.  There's no way around that.

The simplest way to avoid instantiating any objects is to make `mult` a static method.  Just do this instead (add the word 'static'):

```
public class Tester2 {  
  static int[][] mult(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    ...
    return c;
  }
}
```

Then you can call `mult` like this:

```
Tester2.mult(a, b)
```